# Plain text view of a document in Couchbase GUI

Tags: nosql, couchbase

I am using Couchbase and testing it on my local computer with ASP.NET. I've inserted some data into a sample document and I can read the data using ASP.NET C# Driver for Couchbase. The thing is that when I logged in to the cluster management GUI and look at the document, I get to see lots of characters with no meaning, can't actually see a text representation of the document that I've inserted. With MongoDB, BigCouch, RavenDB the data is plain and simple JOSN document and its easy to update a single document. Am I missing something here?

In my .NET application I have this code:

```
 var client = new CouchbaseClient();


 client.Store(StoreMode.Add, "aaa", "sample_data");
 client.Dispose();
```

What I get is in the console when I view the document:

```
"Y29tcGFyaXNvbl9pZDogMQ=="
```

This is a binary format, not JSON. **Using CouchBase 2.0 beta**

Comment: You can view any document through the Couchbase admin console, but it is difficult to guess as to what you might be doing wrong without more information. Can you link to so pictures of what the issue is and describe what you expect to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug of Couchbase 2.0 GUI display.Now I use couchbase-server-2.0.0-1723.x86_64 in RHEL 6.0,and create new document with Coubase 2.0 GUI.When I insert under json:

```
{
  "_id": "100",
  "name": "Thomas",
  "dept": "Sales",
  "salary": 5000
}
```

,then save while list base64 string:

```
"eyJfaWQiOiIxMDAiLCJuYW1lIjoiVGhvbWFzIiwiZGVwdCI6IlNhbGVzIiwic2FsYXJ5Ijo1MDAwfQ=="
```

I can follow this post:[base64 value display in GUI (Beta 2.0)](http://www.couchbase.com/forums/thread/base64-value-display-gui-beta-2-0),to fix javascript code in this path:

```
/opt/couchbase/lib/ns_server/erlang/lib/ns_server-2.0.0r_331_g08fb51b/priv/public/js
```

Fianlly,Clean the browser cache and login Couchbase 2.0 GUI agian.The documents will display:

```
"{"_id":"100","name":"Thomas","dept":"Sales","salary":5000}"
```

It's corrent.

Comment: If you make any document using the UI with `_id` in it, it will consider it non-JSON and not be displayed in the editor.

Answer (score 2):

In Couchbase Server 2.0, if you store invalid JSON as the value in the key/value pair that you save, you will see a Base64 encoded version of the item you've saved.  Since "sample_data" is not a valid JSON document, Couchbase Server treats it like a byte array.  When you view the bytes, they're Base64 encoded.  Instead, if you change your store method to something like the following:

```
client.Store(StoreMode.Add, "aaa", "{ \"message\" : \"sample_data\" }");
```

you'd then see the actual JSON document.

The Getting Started guide for the latest Beta of the Couchbase Client has more information on working with JSON and views with Couchbase Server 2.0 - http://www.couchbase.com/develop/net/next.

Comment: used a JSON seralizer and it works, but your example doesn't seem to work. Thanks

Comment: That code should work, I just tested it and it showed up correctly.  If you executed it using StoreMode.Add and had an existing key "aaa" then the operation would have failed.  If you run it instead with StoreMode.Set, it should work.